# MySQL return first row related to a given id

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with a MySQL database, trying to grab statistics on the number of users *in a department* who have completed a certain task within a timeline.

My problem is this: certain users are doing tasks multiple times. I was able to construct a query which returns the number of done tasks and total users per group, but I need to only count one "task" per user. For this reason, I'm getting results like "150% of [department] has completed the task" when only one person has completed enough to fill the requirement for their whole department.

Here is the existing query:

```
SELECT total.department, total_count, IFNULL(done, 0) as done_count, ROUND((IFNULL(done, 0) / total_count)*100, 2) as percent 
FROM (SELECT department, COUNT(*) total_count FROM agents GROUP BY department) total 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.department as department, COUNT(*) as done FROM agents a, tasks p WHERE p.task_responses_id IS NOT NULL AND (p.agent1_id = a.id OR p.agent2_id = a.id) 
GROUP BY a.department) done ON done.department = total.department;
```

Which returns a table like this (department names sanitized):

```
+------------------+-------------+------------+---------+
| department       | total_count | done_count | percent |
+------------------+-------------+------------+---------+
| a                |           2 |          0 |    0.00 |
| b                |          10 |          1 |   10.00 |
| c                |           2 |          0 |    0.00 |
| d                |           1 |          0 |    0.00 |
| e                |           2 |          2 |  100.00 |
| f                |           1 |          0 |    0.00 |
| g                |           3 |          6 |  200.00 |
| h                |           4 |          0 |    0.00 |
| i                |           4 |          1 |   25.00 |
+------------------+-------------+------------+---------+
```

As you can see, the department "g" has done_count > total_count due to one person in that department doing it multiple times. I need to take the task table which looks like this:

```
+-----+----------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------+------+
| id  | reservation_id | agent1_id | agent2_id | task_responses_id     | last_contact        | dnc  |
+-----+----------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------+------+
| 128 |        6457633 |         9 |      NULL |                    24 | 2015-10-06 00:00:00 |    1 |
| 130 |        6799659 |        10 |      NULL |                    25 | 2015-10-06 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 145 |        7004981 |        36 |      NULL |                    28 | 2015-10-08 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 150 |        7091836 |        36 |      NULL |                    29 | 2015-10-08 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 152 |        7128330 |        36 |      NULL |                    30 | 2015-10-08 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 155 |        7165876 |        16 |      NULL |                    35 | 2015-10-08 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 166 |        7308234 |        36 |      NULL |                    31 | 2015-10-08 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 171 |        7333373 |        36 |      NULL |                    33 | 2015-10-08 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 173 |        7408857 |        37 |      NULL |                    34 | 2015-10-08 00:00:00 | NULL |
+-----+----------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------+------+
```

And if we've already retrieved a row for a given agent id, I want to not grab any others for their ID.

Thank you so much for your help! I'm happy to clarify any questions you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be achieved by replacing the "count(*)" in the 3rd line with "count(distinct a.id)"

This way, if the same agent id exists more than once, it will be counted only once.

So the query would look like this:

```
SELECT total.department, total_count, IFNULL(done, 0) as done_count, ROUND((IFNULL(done, 0) / total_count)*100, 2) as percent 
FROM (SELECT department, COUNT(*) total_count FROM agents GROUP BY department) total 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.department as department, COUNT(distinct a.id) as done FROM agents a, tasks p WHERE p.task_responses_id IS NOT NULL AND (p.agent1_id = a.id OR p.agent2_id = a.id) 
GROUP BY a.department) done ON done.department = total.department;
```

Comment: DISTINCT is almost always the wrong solution for this kind of problem, and it certainly is in this case. You are asking the DBMS to compute a result set (via the LEFT JOIN), then to find the existence of any row in a group, you simply discard the actual rows. The process requires an internal sort operation which is much more costly than you need.

Comment: @cliffordheath There's a difference between a "wrong" solution, and a "suboptimal" solution. The solution you provided is wrong, because it does not give the percentage of agents who performed the task. My solution might be suboptimal, but it is not wrong, and it is the closest to the query in the question, so it's easier to understand.

Comment: My first solution was not wrong, but incomplete (I did that to improve clarity). Yours yields the right answer, but in the wrong way. It's a common practise to over-use DISTINCT, but it's still wrong, for two reasons. It does not reflect the OP's question which was "trying to grab statistics on the number of users in a department who have completed a certain task within a timeline." whereas both my versions implement exactly that query. And there's the performance angle, which is not widely-known.

Comment: Again, there is a difference between "wrong" and "suboptimal"... You say it yields the right answer, so it cannot be wrong. Saying that it does not reflect the OP's question is strange because your (first) answer seems to be the one that did not reflect the OP's question, and did not look at the sample answer provided by the OP, while this solution clearly did. Your second version uses multiple nested subqueries, which I really doubt will be any better in terms of performance.

Comment: You may not think it would perform differently, but I have decades of close examination of query plans that says otherwise. Using DISTINCT often fools good query optimisers into doing a costly SORT operation, and it certainly fools MySQL's crappy optimiser. To satisfy yourself of this, consider what happens if some agents have done a million tasks that qualify. Or just try it. But your lack of gratitude at learning that is noted, so I'll refrain from helping you again.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the number of agents per department in the same query as the number who have completed a task, you could use a sub-query in the select list, but this will not perform as well. Instead I recommend the following, which is more complex but will perform optimally:

```
SELECT  d.department, count(*) as dept_count, sum(d.done) as done_count
FROM    (SELECT *,
                (CASE WHEN EXISTS(
                        SELECT * FROM tasks
                        WHERE    (agents.id = tasks.agent1_id OR agents.id = tasks.agent2_id)
                          AND    tasks.task_responses_id IS NOT NULL
                    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                ) as done
        FROM    agents
        ) as d
GROUP BY department;
```

This version uses an inner query over the agents table that adds a "done" column which has the value 1 if that agent qualifies, 0 otherwise. The outer query counts all rows, but also sums up the number of 1's to get the done_count.

Comment: Thank you! This query is the one we'll end up moving to production with.

The final version looks like this:

`SELECT d.department, count(*) as total_count, sum(d.done) as done_count, ROUND((SUM(d.done) / COUNT(*))*100, 2) as percent 
FROM (SELECT *, (CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT * FROM tasks 
WHERE (agents.id = tasks.agent1_id OR agents.id = tasks.agent2_id) 
AND tasks.tasks_responses_id IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as done FROM agents) as d 
GROUP BY department`

Though I'm not able to make this look neat in mini-Markdown...

Comment: Happily! And I've given you one, I just don't have enough rep to make it count. Once my rep goes above 15, it's supposed to count.

Answer (score -2):

You should use an EXISTS subquery (this is also called a semi-join). You want to count the number of users for whom some condition holds. I don't have your full schema, but it looks like this should do what you want:

```
SELECT department, count(*) AS done_count
FROM   agents
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM tasks
    WHERE   (agents.id = tasks.agent1_id OR agents.id = tasks.agent2_id)
      AND   tasks.task_responses_id IS NOT NULL
)
GROUP BY department;
```

This query says almost exactly what you asked for in your first paragraph. By avoiding the LEFT JOIN and the DISTINCT operator, you give the DBMS a chance at constructing a sensible query that doesn't take way longer to run than it needs to.

Comment: This query works, but doesn't include the total count of agents in each department, which I can't seem to figure out how to do without joining a department, count somewhere along the way. Am I missing something remarkably simple? There's only one cup of coffee coursing through my veins right now.

Comment: The count of agents in a department is a different query. There are several ways to include that. I'll add another answer below.

Comment: Looking at the sample query in the question and its result, this solution is incorrect, since it does not give the percentage of agents in every department who performed the task. It only gives the number of agents who performed the task in some departments. Also, if dept "c" has no agents who performed the task, that department won't even show up in the result.

Comment: My solution answers the question posed in the first paragraph, not the implicit question (not asked) of how to get the percentage. As you can see, I have now provided both answers.

Comment: Well then, providing an incomplete solution based only on the first paragraph without carefully looking at the sample provided by the OP.

Comment: No part of the question asked that there should be a count for every department. If your query returns zero counts, then it is also wrong

Comment: This is going nowhere. Please scroll up to the beginning of the page and take a good look at the OP (all of it, not just the first 3 lines), and look carefully at the first table). Have a nice day, sir!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91798/discussion-between-cliffordheath-and-a-el-helw).